# different formulas for the fourier series.

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Quick question, I see both of these

$$f(w) = a_0 + \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} (a_kcos(kw) + b_ksin(kw) \quad f(w) = \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} (a_kcos(kw) + b_ksin(kw)$$

Why the difference ( $a_0$ and $\frac{a_0}{2}$)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take the second definition, then the downside is that you have to divide $a_0$ by $2$.  The upside is that now all of the coefficients $a_k$ can be concisely described by
$$
a_k = \frac 2{T_0}\int_{0}^{T_0} f(t) \cos\left(\frac{2 \pi k t}{T_0} \right)\,dt
$$
whereas in the first case, we would have to write the definition something like
$$
a_k = 
\begin{cases}
\frac 2{T_0}\int_{0}^{T_0} f(t) \cos\left(\frac{2 \pi k t}{T_0} \right)\,dt & k \geq 1\\
\frac 1{T_0} \int_0^{T_0} f(t)\,dt & k = 0
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Thanks, could I get a reference where this is shown?

Comment: Is [this sufficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Fourier_series#Definition) as a reference?

Comment: Yes sometimes I'm just scared I won't understand completely.

Comment: Feel free to comment here if you have a quick question. If you're really looking for a more thorough reference, however, perhaps you should post a question asking for one.